# Создание UITableView в классе UIView и использование в качестве property

Tags: ios, mvc, uitableview

На сториборд вьюконтроллера поместил UIView и сделал ее наследником созданного мною класса. В этом классе описывается отрисовка таблицы на вьюхе. Вот описание класса:

**UIView.h**

```
@interface View : UIView

@property (strong, nonatomic) UITableView *contentTable;

@end
```

**UIView.m**

```
@implementation View

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    self.contentTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, rect.size.width, rect.size.height) style:UITableViewStylePlain];

    [self addSubview:self.contentTable];
}

@end
```

Таблица отображается, но если ей назначить DataSource, то он не будет работать. 
Код из вьюконтроллера:

**UIViewController.m**

```
@interface TRDetailTicketViewController () <UITableViewDataSource>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet View *mainView;

@end

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.mainView.contentTable setDataSource:self];
}
```

Ни один метод DataSource не вызывается (они описаны ниже, не стал сюда их включать). 
Можно это сделать через метод, который будет возвращать UITableView, но это не то, что мне нужно.

Comment: предположу, что у вас назначение dataSource происходит до создания таблицы. чтоб это проверить поставьте брейкпоинт либо NSLog

Comment: @Max Mikheyenko как раз уже пришел к этому, но так и не понял как решить. Выяснилось, что вначале инициализируется ViewController, а потом View, поэтому все, что я делаю в контроллере переопределяется затем во вьюхе.

Comment: попробуйте перенести назначение датасурса в viewDidAppear, и там же сразу сделать reloadData

Comment: Все-равно вью грузится после viewDidAppear. Я свел задачу к минимуму - вместо таблицы добавил вьюху и в контроллере пытаюсь поменять ее цвет. Даже это не получается, потому что она переопределяется во вьюхе.

Comment: тогда, я бы предложил все таки не изобретать велосипед, и перенести весь код в уонтроллер. примерно как предложили в ответе ниже

Answer (score 0):

Вроде, не очень хорошая идея инициализировать таблицу в `drawRect` используйте лучше для этого метод `init` (хотя для этого надо переопределить все методы `init`'a, из которых будет вызываться инициализация таблицы) или `awakeFromNib`, а размеры задавать в каком-нибудь `layoutSubviews`.
Касательно вашего вопроса, какой смысл делать таблицу во вьюшке, а датасоурс и делегат делать в контроллере? По-моему мнение, перенесите таблицу полностью в контроллер, либо полностью во вью и там уже назначайте датасоурс\делегат\инициализацию, я бы предпочел перенести в контроллер.

Comment: Я инициализировал таблицу и в `drawRect` , и в `layoutSubviews`, результат одинаков. Разделяю их для того, чтобы в классе UIView была только отрисовка UI, а в контроллере его обработка. На самом деле там будет куда больше элементов, в том числе и таблиц. Я упростил до 1 таблицы только для примера, чтобы поняли мою проблему. А если я буду и отрисовку и обработку делать в контроллере, то получится громоздкий контроллер в тысячу строк кода.

Comment: Я не говорил, чтобы вы инициализировали в layoutSubviews, я говорил, чтобы в этом методе размеры задавали, инициализацию надо делать в других, в которых я написал выше. Насчет большого количества кода, что поделать, MVC такой MVC, посмотрите в сторону MVVM.